podman - Failed to stop any containers by using "sudo podman stop"
I have encountered a problem with podman. I have successfully ran couple containers within it. But when I issue "sudo podman stop/restart xxx", I always get below error (used pgadmin4 as an example), then the container status stuck at "Stopping". To recover from it, I have to restart the computer.
I found this issue only present when run the container using sudo podman, using podman without sudo are all good.
WARN[0010] StopSignal SIGTERM failed to stop container mypgadmin4 in 10 seconds, resorting to SIGKILL
Error: given PID did not die within timeout

Below is my environment
Ubuntu 24.04
Kernel: 6.8.0-35-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC
Remote login through ssh
Podman is installed through Ubuntu official repos using apt install.

Podman details:
Client:       Podman Engine
Version:      4.9.3
API Version:  4.9.3
Go Version:   go1.22.1
Built:        Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

podman ps details
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                            COMMAND     CREATED       STATUS      PORTS                 NAMES
03a444daf9a5  docker.io/dpage/pgadmin4:latest              20 hours ago  Stopping    0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp  mypgadmin4

Podman inspect details:
[
     {
          "Id": "03a444daf9a56b0e1d662da466ef657d3e760b83966b1b931f085b9ec4c2dee5",
          "Created": "2024-06-07T08:13:52.48940452Z",
          "Path": "/entrypoint.sh",
          "Args": [
               "/entrypoint.sh"
          ],
          "State": {
               "OciVersion": "1.1.0",
               "Status": "stopping",
               "Running": false,
               "Paused": false,
               "Restarting": false,
               "OOMKilled": false,
               "Dead": false,
               "Pid": 1354,
               "ConmonPid": 1352,
               "ExitCode": 0,
               "Error": "container 03a444daf9a56b0e1d662da466ef657d3e760b83966b1b931f085b9ec4c2dee5 must be in Created or Stopped state to be started: container state improper",
               "StartedAt": "2024-06-08T04:16:37.753214803Z",
               "FinishedAt": "2024-06-08T04:13:29.582636564Z",
               "Health": {
                    "Status": "",
                    "FailingStreak": 0,
                    "Log": null
               },
               "CheckpointedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
               "RestoredAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
               "StoppedByUser": true
          },
          "Image": "52957d72b44aeb31109430b2b681a4867a94825c02ac7cfeca31decfb65a4e18",
          "ImageDigest": "sha256:61fd25f428c155027fb2aa74b913d317af11a14f55e6135484b5e86a8840520b",
          "ImageName": "docker.io/dpage/pgadmin4:latest",
          "Rootfs": "",
          "Pod": "",
          "ResolvConfPath": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/03a444daf9a56b0e1d662da466ef657d3e760b83966b1b931f085b9ec4c2dee5/userdata/resolv.conf",
          "HostnamePath": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/03a444daf9a56b0e1d662da466ef657d3e760b83966b1b931f085b9ec4c2dee5/userdata/hostname",
          "HostsPath": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/03a444daf9a56b0e1d662da466ef657d3e760b83966b1b931f085b9ec4c2dee5/userdata/hosts",
          "StaticDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay-containers/03a444daf9a56b0e1d662da466ef657d3e760b83966b1b931f085b9ec4c2dee5/userdata",
          "OCIConfigPath": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay-containers/03a444daf9a56b0e1d662da466ef657d3e760b83966b1b931f085b9ec4c2dee5/userdata/config.json",
          "OCIRuntime": "crun",
          "ConmonPidFile": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/03a444daf9a56b0e1d662da466ef657d3e760b83966b1b931f085b9ec4c2dee5/userdata/conmon.pid",
          "PidFile": "/run/containers/storage/overlay-containers/03a444daf9a56b0e1d662da466ef657d3e760b83966b1b931f085b9ec4c2dee5/userdata/pidfile",
          "Name": "mypgadmin4",
          "RestartCount": 0,
          "Driver": "overlay",
          "MountLabel": "",
          "ProcessLabel": "",
          "AppArmorProfile": "containers-default-0.57.4",
          "EffectiveCaps": null,
          "BoundingCaps": [
               "CAP_CHOWN",
               "CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE",
               "CAP_FOWNER",
               "CAP_FSETID",
               "CAP_KILL",
               "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE",
               "CAP_SETFCAP",
               "CAP_SETGID",
               "CAP_SETPCAP",
               "CAP_SETUID",
               "CAP_SYS_CHROOT"
          ],
          "ExecIDs": [],
          "GraphDriver": {
               "Name": "overlay",
               "Data": {
                    "LowerDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/a5c7f871d710f522023ca5dfdad42ae08922c22a6521ef6586cfc5be868d455e/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/dc86a1c3f885aa3c52c12d8d284601453b8351a39d389643c68ef48743e1d1cf/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/9b97c28998b2e858ec85ca6bd90bd5bac65796ec9ba935cfc207e5b2a6cdbd8f/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/449060aaadfe49aa1bff299b09d0d7cfed4ee0613aac066a6a6c5cc31297b422/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/ee986652d35f7ce871f3ff7ec6bccfbaf9d2cca2fbd84d2f4ec9dc985a69d1fc/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/17bb2f5a79fd2fa0d6392b0c285632f551cdba15f00d7fd8370016fbf29ed38c/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/6874fb546f2470531ac32bfeb5cb02e559ed7ed0ee8948e01f40d3f5bc90cb34/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/bfcef14a6c361df75f0788cf35434d68d59683667538048dc4563146bd599aa6/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/2a1fd15f5b430cbeaaaa09526b890da406b895ac1dbb7507d4f17bb84500ca6d/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/e1f4108a9613a1b6d2a06b76d96166e8173849d406c0293c453459801c17e5f0/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/a8581de914bb2816ffe235a6b98aa3761d188cbba6b7e0b45d20e7329d8d2f73/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/74f98c324854f69f351d8c3c17822ca47b473d63f268c4bb8d2ed1d1dc966ded/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/d4fa294b332976ab868c91a9b2115e89138635f3439dc0255a7bcfeae3fc67f2/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/9c212d5aefe774f9ed137f7a5e497dd71046ef0f80a7bae994e0857068879fd3/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/a6e7ea5b0f1081955cb735c56d1d4ef51c516ec66ce897b063957d1a9218cc0e/diff:/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/02f2bcb26af5ea6d185dcf509dc795746d907ae10c53918b6944ac85447a0c72/diff",
                    "MergedDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/f5378473fddf6cce0f561698ecc0d35ff6cb2df7762bc5b16d93811671157310/merged",
                    "UpperDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/f5378473fddf6cce0f561698ecc0d35ff6cb2df7762bc5b16d93811671157310/diff",
                    "WorkDir": "/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/f5378473fddf6cce0f561698ecc0d35ff6cb2df7762bc5b16d93811671157310/work"
               }
          },
          "Mounts": [
               {
                    "Type": "volume",
                    "Name": "fcc5478dcd526de788efa231bae5f93c9466e9ae40b1ce98af6930c11d1b0941",
                    "Source": "/var/lib/containers/storage/volumes/fcc5478dcd526de788efa231bae5f93c9466e9ae40b1ce98af6930c11d1b0941/_data",
                    "Destination": "/var/lib/pgadmin",
                    "Driver": "local",
                    "Mode": "",
                    "Options": [
                         "nodev",
                         "exec",
                         "nosuid",
                         "rbind"
                    ],
                    "RW": true,
                    "Propagation": "rprivate"
               }
          ],
          "Dependencies": [],
          "NetworkSettings": {
               "EndpointID": "",
               "Gateway": "10.88.0.1",
               "IPAddress": "10.88.0.4",
               "IPPrefixLen": 16,
               "IPv6Gateway": "",
               "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
               "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
               "MacAddress": "da:52:dd:8b:88:dc",
               "Bridge": "",
               "SandboxID": "",
               "HairpinMode": false,
               "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
               "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
               "Ports": {
                    "443/tcp": null,
                    "80/tcp": [
                         {
                              "HostIp": "",
                              "HostPort": "5050"
                         }
                    ]
               },
               "SandboxKey": "/run/netns/netns-e16d008f-10f1-81b1-8f01-851badc15f3a",
               "Networks": {
                    "podman": {
                         "EndpointID": "",
                         "Gateway": "10.88.0.1",
                         "IPAddress": "10.88.0.4",
                         "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                         "IPv6Gateway": "",
                         "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                         "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                         "MacAddress": "da:52:dd:8b:88:dc",
                         "NetworkID": "podman",
                         "DriverOpts": null,
                         "IPAMConfig": null,
                         "Links": null,
                         "Aliases": [
                              "03a444daf9a5"
                         ]
                    }
               }
          },
          "Namespace": "",
          "IsInfra": false,
          "IsService": false,
          "KubeExitCodePropagation": "invalid",
          "lockNumber": 6,
          "Config": {
               "Hostname": "03a444daf9a5",
               "Domainname": "",
               "User": "pgadmin",
               "AttachStdin": false,
               "AttachStdout": false,
               "AttachStderr": false,
               "Tty": false,
               "OpenStdin": false,
               "StdinOnce": false,
               "Env": [
                    "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                    "container=podman",
                    "PYTHONPATH=/pgadmin4",
                    "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=xxxx@live.com",
                    "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=xxxx",
                    "HOME=/home/pgadmin",
                    "HOSTNAME=03a444daf9a5"
               ],
               "Cmd": null,
               "Image": "docker.io/dpage/pgadmin4:latest",
               "Volumes": null,
               "WorkingDir": "/pgadmin4",
               "Entrypoint": "/entrypoint.sh",
               "OnBuild": null,
               "Labels": null,
               "Annotations": {
                    "io.container.manager": "libpod",
                    "org.opencontainers.image.stopSignal": "15"
               },
               "StopSignal": 15,
               "HealthcheckOnFailureAction": "none",
               "CreateCommand": [
                    "podman",
                    "run",
                    "--name",
                    "mypgadmin4",
                    "-p",
                    "5050:80",
                    "-e",
                    "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=xxxx@live.com",
                    "-e",
                    "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=xxxx",
                    "-d",
                    "docker.io/dpage/pgadmin4:latest"
               ],
               "Umask": "0022",
               "Timeout": 0,
               "StopTimeout": 10,
               "Passwd": true,
               "sdNotifyMode": "container"
          },
          "HostConfig": {
               "Binds": [
                    "fcc5478dcd526de788efa231bae5f93c9466e9ae40b1ce98af6930c11d1b0941:/var/lib/pgadmin:rprivate,rw,nodev,exec,nosuid,rbind"
               ],
               "CgroupManager": "systemd",
               "CgroupMode": "private",
               "ContainerIDFile": "",
               "LogConfig": {
                    "Type": "journald",
                    "Config": null,
                    "Path": "",
                    "Tag": "",
                    "Size": "0B"
               },
               "NetworkMode": "bridge",
               "PortBindings": {
                    "80/tcp": [
                         {
                              "HostIp": "",
                              "HostPort": "5050"
                         }
                    ]
               },
               "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Name": "",
                    "MaximumRetryCount": 0
               },
               "AutoRemove": false,
               "VolumeDriver": "",
               "VolumesFrom": null,
               "CapAdd": [],
               "CapDrop": [],
               "Dns": [],
               "DnsOptions": [],
               "DnsSearch": [],
               "ExtraHosts": [],
               "GroupAdd": [],
               "IpcMode": "shareable",
               "Cgroup": "",
               "Cgroups": "default",
               "Links": null,
               "OomScoreAdj": 0,
               "PidMode": "private",
               "Privileged": false,
               "PublishAllPorts": false,
               "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
               "SecurityOpt": [],
               "Tmpfs": {},
               "UTSMode": "private",
               "UsernsMode": "",
               "ShmSize": 65536000,
               "Runtime": "oci",
               "ConsoleSize": [
                    0,
                    0
               ],
               "Isolation": "",
               "CpuShares": 0,
               "Memory": 0,
               "NanoCpus": 0,
               "CgroupParent": "",
               "BlkioWeight": 0,
               "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
               "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
               "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
               "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
               "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
               "CpuPeriod": 0,
               "CpuQuota": 0,
               "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
               "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
               "CpusetCpus": "",
               "CpusetMems": "",
               "Devices": [],
               "DiskQuota": 0,
               "KernelMemory": 0,
               "MemoryReservation": 0,
               "MemorySwap": 0,
               "MemorySwappiness": 0,
               "OomKillDisable": false,
               "PidsLimit": 2048,
               "Ulimits": [
                    {
                         "Name": "RLIMIT_NPROC",
                         "Soft": 4194304,
                         "Hard": 4194304
                    }
               ],
               "CpuCount": 0,
               "CpuPercent": 0,
               "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
               "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
               "CgroupConf": null
          }
     }
]

Can I ask what caused this issue and how can I fix it please?
Thanks in advance!

Just recently had this issue. As to why this happened I am not sure what caused this problem.
What I did to fix it:
The error says: "Error: given PID did not die within timeout" so I figured the PID wasn't being stopped and I needed to manually stop it.
What worked for me was:
podman container inspect <your-container> | grep "\"PID\":" 

Then grab the PID value and kill it manually:
kill -9 <PID>

Here is a one liner for what I mentioned above:
kill -9 $(podman container inspect <your-container>  -f '{{.State.Pid}}')

Edited: here is a cleaner way to do the one liner, thanks to Erik in the comments

Here is another way to print the PID: podman container inspect <your-container>  -f '{{.State.Pid}}'

In config section I see:
"StopSignal": 15,

Try to change to 9.
Also, this command is very useful:
podman container kill -fa

Check and setup containers.conf for these values:

stop_timeout
exit_command_delay


tried podman container kill -a, and get the permission denied error
2024-06-08T08:56:42.047900Z: send signal to pidfd: Permission denied
Error: sending signal to container 03a444daf9a56b0e1d662da466ef657d3e760b83966b1b931f085b9ec4c2dee5: /usr/bin/crun kill 03a444daf9a56b0e1d662da466ef657d3e760b83966b1b931f085b9ec4c2dee5 9 failed: exit status 1

The flag -f is not an option for podman container kill in version 4.9.4
